# Supermicro SuperServer 5037MC-H8TRF PXE boot infinite retry

Tags: boot, pxe-boot, supermicro

I can successfully PXE-boot the blades in a Supermicro SuperServer 5037MC-H8TRF. However if my PXE server is not currently up, the blades try to get a DHCP on each interface once before the boot agent gives up and asks you to press any key to try again.

The PXE-boot agent is Intel boot agent GE v1.3.81.

Is there a way of setting this so that the machines will continually cycle through their NICs attempting to PXE-boot indefinitely?

Answer (score 0):

If you do that you would be creating an endless source of broadcast traffic (DHCPDISCOVERY packets) and no one really wants that; that's why after an attempt to PXE boot on every NIC the firmware stops and wait for user input.
You won't be able to change that behavior on well designed firmware.